# Store values in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I have this functionality which process data returned from a server via websocket. The data is treated differently depending on which page you are on.

```
sock.onmessage = function (e) {
    log(e.data);
}

function returnCurrentPage(m) {
    if (helpers.getCurrentPage() === '#builddetail_page') {
        // For the builddetailpage
        var stepList = $('#stepList > li');
        return realtimePages.buildDetail(m, stepList);
    }
    if (helpers.getCurrentPage() === '#builders_page') {
        var tableRowList = $('.tablesorter-js tbody > tr');
        return realtimePages.buildersPage(m, tableRowList);
    }
}

// Data to be parsed
function log(m) {
    returnCurrentPage(m)
};
```

My problem is that every time log() is envoked, so is returnCurrentPage(). How can I get the returned values from returnCurrentPage() stored in log()? So I won't have to run returnCurrentPage() every time log() is running ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you save the returned value in localStorage?

```
sock.onmessage = function (e) {
    log(e.data);
}

function returnCurrentPage(m) {
    if (helpers.getCurrentPage() === '#builddetail_page') {
        // For the builddetailpage
        var stepList = $('#stepList > li');
        return realtimePages.buildDetail(m, stepList);
    }
    if (helpers.getCurrentPage() === '#builders_page') {
        var tableRowList = $('.tablesorter-js tbody > tr');
        return realtimePages.buildersPage(m, tableRowList);
    }
}

// Data to be parsed
function log(m) {
    if( localStorage.returnPage === undefined )
        localStorage.returnPage = returnCurrentPage(m)
};
```

Comment: I could only get it to work with a quoted 'undefined' but it's still running returnCurrentPage() every time log() is executed

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the values logged in a global variable and clear it as necessary.

Comment: Can you be more precise ?